# Парсинг большого количества RSS лент из Твиттера

Tags: php, парсер, twitter-api, твиттер

Стоит следующая задача: нужно спарсить большое количество RSS лент (юзеры, чьи ленты нужно спарсить, заранее определены) из твиттера. Если парсить напрямую с сайта, то будет большая нагрузка от http запросов. Если юзать API твиттера - то там стоит ограничение, которое возможно помешает с парсингом. Видел еще способ, где прогоняется RSS виджет твиттера через скрипт, и уже из виджета выжимается новостная лента - но он почему то доверия не внушает.
Посоветуйте кто-нибудь, как быть, буду премного благодарен.

Comment: а что такое "большое кол-во"? 10, 100, миллион? может проблема надуманная и кеширование спасет?